# Could not find the correct provider, firestore collections

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting a weird error, can anyone explain why this is and what would be the solution?
I need to compare different collection fields in firestore. I was thinking it might be because I'm using both streambuilder and provider? so one of the context gets 'confused'. If this is so, is there any alternative to what I'm trying to do?

[image: error]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:carpoolapp/shared/loading.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:carpoolapp/models/chatdata.dart';
import 'package:carpoolapp/screens/home/chat_tile.dart';

final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

class preMessageTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _preMessageTabState createState() => _preMessageTabState();
}

class _preMessageTabState extends State<preMessageTab> {

  int count = 0;
  var chats;

  void prov(){
    chats = Provider.of<List<ChatData>>(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    prov();

    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: _firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('messages').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Center(
          child: Loading(),
        );
      }
      else{
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: chats.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            snapshot.data.docs.forEach((doc) {
              if(doc.data()['sender'] == chats[index].uid){
                ++count;
              }
              });
            if(count>=1){
              return ChatTile(chat: chats[index],);
            }
            else{
              return SizedBox(height: 20.0,);
            }
          }
        );
      }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add your provider above this widget? This is clearly stated in the error log. You need to wrap your parent widget, with a changenotifierprovider. The documentation recomends keeping provider as close to your children as possible, but you can start with wrapping it around your Material widget, in your `main()` class.

Comment: I'm already using the ChangeNotifierProvider() in main() for a different provider.

Comment: Great, if you need to add another provider, change it in main to `multiprovider` and this one also. It should work if that one is working correctly and it's at the top of your project.

Comment: Just tried using `multiprovider`, there's no change it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: Keep the multitiprovider because you need it. Did you hot reload or refresh? If this error persists after complete reload, this could mean you are building this widget in a new material route. Which to Flutter/provider is different than the route where you defined multitiprovider. Can you confirm this?

Comment: I've tried both hot reload and rebuilding from scratch.

Comment: What about being in a different route?

Comment: Yes that worked, it seems the route was the issue. I created a 'middleman' dart file and used that to navigate to this tab. That has solved the issue.

Comment: Great! I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that your widget can't access the provider. This could be due to the multiple reasons mentioned in the red screen and debug console.
Mainly, always check that your provider is above your widget.
If you are using more than one provider, use multiProvider.

If the problem still persists, it would mean that the widget you are calling provider from, and your multiprovider, are in two separate material route.

Fixing this issue would solve the problem usually, as you suggested also, using a middleMan widget.

Answer (score 1):

Created another dart file and used that as a 'middleman' to get to the original tab. The route was the issue.

@Huthaifa Thank you for your help.

```
class prepreMessageTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _prepreMessageTabState createState() => _prepreMessageTabState();
}

class _prepreMessageTabState extends State<prepreMessageTab> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<List<ChatData>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService().chatData,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: preMessageTab(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```